# How to stop autoscroll in a reverse RecyclerView for a Chat application in case of imageLoading from url

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, chat, android-glide, fresco

I am facing an issue of autoscrolling of chat items when images are being loaded from the url. Currently I am using glide to load the images.

Reverse list is working fine for text chats and in images also with normal place holders, but when it comes to loading image from url, its focusing on the imageviews and scroll automatically.

I have changed Glide to Picasso but still same issue persists, but the strange thing is if I am using fresco library to load the chat images, autoscroll is not happening there. But currently I am not in a situation to change the imageLoading library in my project, because glide has been using in so many places.

Is there any solution to it? I have checked so many questions related to autoscroll but no one has pointed this image loading one. Please let me know if any solutions to it, thanks :)